# Python regex cuts off javascript variable after first semicolon

Tags: python, python-re

How can I the entire content of the variable, so that getvar() returns `"hello; this should be included"` instead of `"hello`? How would I change the regex pattern to make it work?

```
import re

def getvar(string, variable):
    return re.findall('var ' + variable + ' = (.*?);', string)[0]

print(getvar("""<script>var first_variable = "hello; this should be included";</script>""", 'first_variable'))
```

Comment: Is it ok to assume that the closing semicolon will always be followed by a newline? Otherwise, if you have multiple statements on the same line, it will be ambiguous and probably too hard for regexes.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it, I realized that the closing semicolon is always followed by the ending script tag. Checking for that fixed my problem: re.findall('var ' + variable + ' = (.*?);</script>', string). Thank you for the idea

Comment: Sometimes it's const or let instead of var for the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've provided, we can get that grouping by slightly altering the Regex you've provided.

```
def getvar(string, variable):
return re.findall('var ' + variable + ' = (.*);', string)[0]
```

This will return `"hello; this should be included"`
Although it is important to remember that this method will fail if the string you provide does not find a match.

Comment: Note that this fails for a line that contains multiple statements, such as `getvar('var first_variable = "hello; this should be included";console.log(first_variable);','first_variable')`